# Writing an efficient power function in Rust

Tags: performance, rust, integer-arithmetic

I am writing an efficient squaring method in Rust.  Let's assume that the `Mul` trait of `AbstractNumber` is a black box and that we're only allowed safe, idiomatic Rust.

Below is a first pass which uses repeated squaring for larger indices.  I'm unsure how LLVM will translate Rust arithmetic method calls such as `checked_next_power_of_two()`.

**Does the following look reasonable?  Would it be more efficient to split off the smaller-case branch into its own inlined function?**

```
/// Compute an integer power of this number efficiently with repeated squaring.
pub fn pow(&self, n: u32) -> AbstractNumber {
    let optimization = 5;

    if n < optimization {
        let mut x = Complex::one();

        for _ in 0..n {
            x *= *self;
        }

        x
    } else {
        // l = floor(log_2(n)), r = n - 2^l
        let (l, r) = if n.is_power_of_two() {
            (n.trailing_zeros(), 0)
        } else {
            let p = n.checked_next_power_of_two().unwrap().trailing_zeros() - 1;
            (p, n - 2u32.pow(p))
        };

        let mut x = *self;

        for _ in 0..l {
            x *= x;
        }

        self.pow(r) * x
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use [num::pow::pow](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/pow/fn.pow.html)? In any case, here is how it is implemented:

```
#[inline]
pub fn pow<T: Clone + One + Mul<T, Output = T>>(mut base: T, mut exp: usize) -> T {
    if exp == 0 { return T::one() }

    while exp & 1 == 0 {
        base = base.clone() * base;
        exp >>= 1;
    }
    if exp == 1 { return base }

    let mut acc = base.clone();
    while exp > 1 {
        exp >>= 1;
        base = base.clone() * base;
        if exp & 1 == 1 {
            acc = acc * base.clone();
        }
    }
    acc
}
```

It requires `Clone` in addition to `Mul` (and `One`, but that's not needed if you're not being generic).

There's nothing wrong or unsafe about using bitwise operations in Rust, by the way.

Comment: Thanks - I'll  use this.